# Drylok turning copper pipe green, is it corrosive to metal or copper?

Tags: basement, pipe, waterproofing

Recently had drylok put on my basement walls and some of it got onto the copper pipe water main coming through the wall - and I noticed that it has turned green under the drylok.

Does drylok and copper or metal pipe react in a corrosive manner?

Comment: Copper goes green in just about every situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual suspect when seeing green copper is Copper Chloride (CuCl) which is usually formed indirectly from Copper Oxide.  When elemental Copper is exposed to Oxygen in the air it forms an oxide layer that serves to protect the remaining copper.  Copper Oxide is black but we usually see it as a "tarnish" on the finish.

Your Drylok compound likely contains some Chlorine-based compounds that are reacting with the Copper and/or Copper Oxide and forming the green residue that you are seeing.  I suspect that those compounds in the Drylok are for application purposes only and they evaporate and dissipate quickly over time as the stuff cures.  So I doubt that you're going to have any long-term issues with this.

It would help, however, to carefully read the Drylok installation instructions for any cautions are applying it to materials that it may be incompatible with.

Comment: Probably the ammonia in the Drylok is causing the corrosion. [This Drylok MSDS](https://d2w8l4nyjr77a0.cloudfront.net/resources/Safety-Data-Sheets/DRYLOK_Extreme_Basement_Masonry_Waterproofer_White_-SDS-en-10.pdf) says it contains ammonia.

Comment: should I do something to scrape the paint off the pipes or is it just incidental amounts that doesn't do enough to damage the pipe?